# Error with unicode characters in cseappto

Tags: etoolbox

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

     \cseappto{myList}{entry1}
     \cseappto{myList}{entry2}
     \cseappto{myList}{{\'e}ntry3}
     \cseappto{myList}{entry4}

     \csuse{myList}

\end{document}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. The code above compiles fine with the default texlive from apt (which is kinda outdated, from 2019).

The code above fails to compile with texlive 2021 installed with `install-tl` perl script (full installation). The error is:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
            }
l.12 \csuse{myList}
```

Is this behaviour known? How can I workaround this?

Comment: What’s the reason for `\cseappto`?

Comment: The code is huge, I'm just posting a small portion. I just need to add entries into the list. The list turns into a table later.